Ubuntu SSSD LDAP authenticate with username & email address
As of now I am able to authenticate with Onelogin VLDAP service using the username. I would also like to authenticate with email address in addition to the username.
Some of users are created with their email address as their username and I am unable to authenticate against LDAP with these email addresses as their usernames.
The /etc/sssd/sssd.conf is : https://pastebin.com/raw/jMzmRFC4
The /etc/nsswitch.conf is : https://pastebin.com/raw/s8Eap6HP
The /var/log/sssd/sssd_domain.com.log is :
part#1/3 : https://pastebin.com/raw/mwpcCDx3
part#2/3 : https://pastebin.com/raw/UxfzxkNJ
part#3/3 : https://pastebin.com/raw/VLNTyCzf
BTW: the usernames are:
Working Case: username = abc123
Not Working Case: usernames = ldauser01@mydomain.com,  ldauser02@mydomain.com , ldapuser01@mydomain.com (emailaddress of ldapuser01) ldapuser02@mydomain.com (emailaddress of ldapuser02)
The user ldapuser02@mydomain.com has never authenticated in the system and hence nothing is cached
Please help to resolve this.
I also observed that even after keying the password twice, we cannot login into the Ubuntu GUI, it just returns back to the screen to key in the password

Sometimes succeeds after 2 attempts, and sometimes 3 attempts

The OneLogin VLDAP services are configured as :
Virtual distinguished name
Virtual DN: cn=email,ou=users,dc=mysubdomain,dc=onelogin,dc=com
User Identifier (cn)
Note: When
a. "ldap_user_name = username" in [domain/mydomain.com], we can authenticate with username
b. "ldap_user_name =" in [domain/mydomain.com] blank or the whole line is commented, we cannot authenticate with any user account (username or mail address)
c. "ldap_user_name = mail" in [domain/mydomain.com], we can authenticate with username
How to resolve this ?
